# What's the oldest still-maintained web framework?

Tags: history, web-frameworks

I'm curious as to know how far back web frameworks go (of which I can still use today).

(Just as an FYI I don't consider CGI to be a framework as much as protocol or an interface.)

Answer (score 9):

While "initial releases" and "current versions" may be radically different and/or incompatible, here is a small list I have compiled. While some of the approaches are antiquated, I believe they all fall within the "web framework" category, although this may vary by definition.

Also, check out [Ian Darwin's: Java Web Framework List](http://www.darwinsys.com/jwf/FrameworkList.seam) -- granted it is Java-specific, as the name implies.

---

[ColdFusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion) was first released in 1995. I suspect it is one of the first "frameworks".

[Open BlueDragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueDragon) has been about since 1998. It is a CFML implementation.

[ASP (aka Classic ASP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) debuted in 1998 -- not to be confused with ASP.NET.

[JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) followed suit in 1999. The Servlet model is very much in use today.

[Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) has been around in some form since 1999.

[Tapestry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tapestry) may have been available about 2000.

[Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal), perhaps more of a "CMS", was released in 2001.

[HTML::Mason](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/HTML-Mason-1.46/lib/HTML/Mason.pm) was on CPAN by 2001.

[ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) was released in 2002 (along with .NET 1.0).

[Seaside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaside) has been around [since 2004](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Duca04eSeaside.pdf).

[Wicket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wicket) has been about since at least 2004.

[Ruby On Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) had a release in 2004. [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28Web_framework%29), arguably the "Python counterpart" of the time, was released in 2005. The "PHP counterpart", [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP), was also released in 2005.

[Pylons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) is circa 2005, but has been superseded by [Pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_%28web_framework%29).

Comment: Can't help but notice that whilst mentioning PHP in the ruby on rails you haven't actually put PHP which is still a very active framework. PHP was released in 1995

Comment: @Manatherin PHP is a language (albeit with highly embedded output and an increasing number of "core methods") and Ruby is a language. Ruby On Rails is a *framework* written in Ruby and likewise CakePHP, which is mentioned, is a *framework* in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Project [Xanadu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Xanadu), Ted Nelson's 1960 hypertext model.  Still alive today.

Answer (score 1):

First time I heard of a javascript framework it was **`prototype.js`**
*Everybody* went irrationally crazy about it.

Then came **scriptaculous** and **mootools**, I ignore in what order.
They where based over prototype. *Some* went crazy over it.

Then... *(drumroll)* **jQuery**, and guess what?
No-one bothered.

Then **dojo**, and some took notice.

Then *everybody* suddenly got *tsunami-crazy* about **jQuery**.

The newest one is most certainly **Ample SDK**.

Comment: Are these things 'web frameworks'? Is jQuery not just a javascript library?

Comment: They are *totally* **javascript frameworks**. Libraries (like dunno, `cssQuery`) are different as they don't impose a writing style and a core foundation of libraries on you. The question was (and is) pretty vague about what kind of frameworks (or language) it is referring to.

Comment: And javascript is **so much more** *generic "web"* than other server side frameworks. ;) ...so many languages and environments on the server side...

Answer (score 0):

Struts was around [since June 2003](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/struts/struts-legacy/)

Comment: [Struts has been around circa 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts).